# How to configure Dockerfile and docker-compose to deploy two containers to docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to migrate working docker config files (Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml) so they deploy working local docker configuration to docker hub.

Tried multiple config file settings.

I have the following Dockerfile and, below, the docker-compose.yml that uses it. When I run "docker-compose up", I successfully get two containers running that can either be accessed independently or will talk to each other via the "db" and the database "container_name". So far so good.

What I cannot figure out is how to take this configuration (the files below) and modify them so I get the same behavior on docker hub. Being able to have working local containers is necessary for development, but others need to use these containers on docker hub so I need to deploy there.

--

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.20-jre8

COPY ./services.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

--

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
   app:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8089:8080"
      volumes:
        -  /Users/user/Library/apache-tomcat-9.0.7/conf/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
      depends_on: 
        - db

   db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      container_name: test-mysql-docker
      ports:
           - 3307:3306
      volumes:
       - ./ZipCodeLookup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ZipCodeLookup.sql
      environment:
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "thepass"
```

Expect to see running containers on docker hub, but cannot see how these files need to be modified to get that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `image` attribute.

```
app:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
      image: docker-hub-username/app
```

Replace "docker-hub-username" with your username. Then run `docker-compose push app`

Comment: This sort of works except that when I do a docker run my-docker-hub-username/app and it downloads and runs the app (it says on port 8089 per my config), I get an "unable to connect" error in the browser. Also, this doesn't bring down required MySQL.  So, if I also need to push MySQL how do I bring all the containers down (both) so I can run them as they work locally? I'm confused why Tomcat isn't actually reachable based on the terminal output also. Thanks.

Comment: Also...when I run docker-compose locally, it builds both services, starts them and they work. I can't figure out how to replicate this behavior with docker-hub. If I need to manually push both images to docker hub, then as I said above, it remains a mystery to me how I would bring both down so they run and work together like when I built them locally. Appreciate your reply above.